# Grails 3.0.9 and Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-3.0.9

I add Spring Security to Grails 3.0.9 and use Spring Security.

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.9.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.9.RELEASE'
```

And I run application and I have this errors:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:52) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:330) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:319) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at up2you2.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75) ~[spring-boot-1.2.6.RELEASE.jar:1.2.6.RELEASE]

  (...)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

When I deactive Spring Security this is project run. 
Please help me.
Adibak

Comment: The error output isn't very helpful unfortunately. Try removing the dependencies for the 2 Spring Security jars and using version 3.0.0.M2 of the plugin instead.

Comment: do you need embedded tomcat? could you post your buildConfig, also if it contains a line as `compile org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.41` try commenting it

Comment: Hello, problem was in version gradle. In grails 3.0.9 is gradle ver.  2.3 and i updated to ver. 2.9 and this runnig. Greeting